# SQL Server: how to export a table

Tags: sql-server

how can I export a SQL Server table to Mysql ? I guess I need to export a .sql file compatible...

thanks

Comment: Do you want just the table structure or the data as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Right Click on database Icon > Tasks > Generate Scripts
follow istructions and export a specific table as .cvs

Comment: +1 for being the only person seemingly knowing the tools already provided, while the other answers at this time get into nice disputes about additional tools - which are totally not needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to BCP the data out into a CSV or some other format flat file and import those into mySQL.

Another way is to use a SSMS add-in called [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which has the option to generate insert statements.

Comment: I can recommended the SSMS POwer Tools pack that @Mladen Prajdic
has written.

Comment: mhm, ok given myTable and myServer, could you write down the command and where I should type it (Windows terminal ?) Sorry I'm totally new to it.

Comment: Good plug for your tool! I'd not heard of it before but it looks very useful so I'll give it a test.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more ? I've installed SSMS Tools Pack.. now how can I export my table for mySQL ?

Comment: there are pictures that show you how on the features page. Basicaly you right click on the table or database tree node in SSMS and got to SSMS Tools -> Generate Insert statements. That's about it.
Date format for teh exported SQL can be in it's Options

Comment: ok thanks. I'm now trying to import the file with phpmyadmin in mySql and I got error near: USE [SOData]; I guess the database is not available so it creates this problems. I thought the .sql file contained all the information I need, but it seems still related to the database. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: only data is scripted. SSMS already has the ability to script schema, so you'll have to do with that.

Comment: @Mladen: I've did it with SSMS Tools indeed. And now I have my .sql file. But i cannot import it with phpmyadmin in my mysql database

Comment: oh wait, is a problem if the mysql database is on another server ?

Comment: well i've never imported into the mySQL, but you might try to increase the batch size to remove Raiserror messages.
Different server shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below link, maybe it can help you.

[MSSQL to MySQL](http://www.convert-in.com/mss2sql.htm)